# Group permission doesn't work for group

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

I'm trying to give me permissions to write on a file owned by `www-data`

```
me@home $ touch my_tralala && chmod 660 my_tralala
me@home $ sudo chown www-data:www-data my_tralala
me@home $ groups me
me : me adm cdrom sudo www-data plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker
```

As you can see I have `www-data` in my group, but I can't touch the file

```
me@home $ touch my_tralala
touch: cannot touch ‘my_tralala’: Permission denied
```

Certainly there is something I'm not getting here.

How can I touch `my_tralala` (without ACL) ?

Comment: There is no *filename* in the second command, chown. Is it an error in writing it up, or in the real attempt to make it work?

Comment: Right, I just forgot it in the question, thx

Comment: what are the directory's permissions and ownership?

Comment: I am in my home directory (I've been able to touch `my_tralala` before changing the owner)

Comment: Use `id` to find if you are really in group www-data in the current process. `groups` only looks in the /etc files. If the change is recent you may need to re-login.

Comment: I tried it also, it showed me `www-data` too